# Cláusula de limitación de responsabilidad

Tags: discusión

Después de ver en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17987/630) de @paul-vargas una claúsula de "Limitación de Responsabilidad" ante el procedimiento que detallaba, me pregunto si todos deberíamos hacer lo mismo. En las [condiciones de uso](http://stackexchange.com/legal) queda claro que StackOverflow queda exonerado de cualquier responsabilidad que pudiera existir, pudiendo incluso derivar cualquier demanda judicial al suscritor que la hubiera provocado. Sí que se pide al usuario ser responsable con todo lo que aparezca aquí, pero igual no es bastante y sería conveniente poner explícitamente una cláusula junto con la respuesta.

¿Debemos añadir cláusulas de "Limitación de Responsabilidad" en nuestras respuestas? ¿Sólo tendría sentido en algunos casos? ¿Estamos cubiertos por las condiciones de uso?

Comment: Creo que el que StackOverflow esté libre de eso no significa que el autor de la respuesta, en este caso Paul Vargas, esté libre de esos daños colaterales. En mi opinión, si estás seguro de lo que respondes no deberías colocar ese tipo de cláusulas. La única cláusula hasta el momento  que he visto y me parece útil es una cláusula donde indicas que no estás afiliado a una compañía X y que no promocionas su producto.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza quiza preguntando en [law.stackexchange.com](http://law.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el que StackOverflow esté libre de eso no significa que el autor de la respuesta, en este caso Paul Vargas, esté libre de esos daños colaterales. En mi opinión, si estás seguro de lo que respondes no deberías colocar ese tipo de cláusulas. La única cláusula hasta el momento  que he visto y me parece útil es una cláusula donde indicas que no estás afiliado a una compañía X y que no promocionas su producto. Yo he utilizado esta cláusula que menciono en algunas respuestas en el sitio en inglés y por lo menos en una ocasión en el sitio en español, tal como luce en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1967/227):

> Aviso Legal: No estoy asociado de ninguna manera a  ni a su equipo de desarrollo, solo soy un usuario contento con el producto y sus resultados.

Comment: En realidad la cláusula es necesaria justo al revés. Cuando estás afiliado a una compañía X y escribes sobre uno de sus productos tienes la obligación, al menos moralmente, de revelarlo para que quien lo lea sepa que no eres imparcial.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos en este sitio no se puede promocionar ningún producto, eso se considera spam. Por ello ambas cláusulas son válidas: indicando cuando no estás afiliado al producto y cuando sí lo estás.

Comment: @Luiggi_Mendoza. Yo no he mencionado nada acerca de promocionar un producto. Lo que digo es que si estás afiliado a una compañía y escribes sobre un producto de esa compañia (lo cual no es automáticamente spam) es NECESARIO, como mínimo desde un punto de vista moral, que hagas pública tu afiliación a esa compañía. Si no estás afiliado es válido pero no necesario que hagas pública tu no afiliación.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos sucede que si todas o muchas de las publicaciones de un usuario terminan siendo más que nada una promoción al producto o a la compañía, entonces la cuenta puede ser removida por eso mismo. Por ello, ambas cláusulas, para la forma de funcionamiento de este sitio, son válidas.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow en inglés existe desde hace años. Se han dado millones de respuestas; cientos de miles o incluso millones de ellas erróneas. Y muchos de sus usuarios son de los Estados Unidos de América, uno de los países mas litigiosos del mundo. ¿Alguien sabe de algún caso de denuncia a un usuario de StackOverflow en inglés por consejo erróneo?

Me parece que una cláusula así es innecesaria y un desperdicio de tiempo y espacio.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debería existir una opción para agregar a la pregunta y/o respuesta una cláusula de limitación de responsabilidad.

El contenido de esta cláusula debe ser suficientemente clara y general para aplicar a cualquier contenido. *Ejemplo de ello se puede leer en la respuesta de Luiggi Mendoza*.

He leído visto preguntas en Stack Overflow en inglés y en demás sitios de la red de Stack Exchange que poseen la opción para agregar una "especie" de `disclaimer / aviso` - similar al texto opcional que puede tener una recompensa / bounty.

Ejemplos:

- [Pregunta histórica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4092887).
- [Prevenir ediciones a la pregunta / respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4092887)
- Skeptics Stack Exchange requiere que las [respuestas posean referencias](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/34819/30277).

En los casos anteriores, parece que son los moderadores únicamente quienes tienen la posibilidad para agregar estos textos.

Comment: Sí Mauricio, solo los moderadores tenemos el poder de agregar esas cláusulas que mencionas.